# Column from deleted content type stuck in my list

Tags: 2013, list, content-type

I'm not a Sharepoint admin (we currently don't have one), I'm just trying to help. I have a list in Sharepoint that used to have columns in it that, I believe, came from a custom content type. That content type has since been deleted. One of the columns (Workspace) that's no longer in the list is preventing someone from creating a chart based on the list. The column can be selected when editing or creating a view for the list, but can not be seen when looking at the columns in the List Settings. When I add the column to a view it doesn't have any values in it for that particular list.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem or have any idea as to how I would go about fixing this?

Comment: is there any other content type in list?

Comment: There are two content types but neither of those content types have the problem column in them.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the column, then try to remove the it using the powershell. You have to run the powershell on SharePoint server.

```
#Attach to the web and content type
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Sales Document"]

#Get link to the columnn from the web
$spFieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink ($web.Fields["Aliases"])

#Remove the column from the content type and update
$ct.FieldLinks.Delete($spFieldLink.Id)
$ct.Update()

#Dispose of the web object
$web.Dispose()
```

Source: http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/cant-remove-site-column-from-content.html